# Image upload works on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-s3, file-upload, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Angular app with node.js as backend. I have a file uploading component that works great when using desktop.

on iOs device however, i can upload all photos BUT .heic files.
now I tested the file upload on mobile when I ran the server locally on my local IP and it also worked

So I'm really confused why it is happening.

Worth to mention I'm using S3 for my angular app and ElasticBeanstalk for my node.js server.

I belive the problem is coming from the AWS services since everything works fine when I'm using local servers.

here are some piece of the code:

```
    <!-- Image Upload -->
<div *ngIf="currentStepIndex === 0"
     class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-full w-full">
  <h1 class="font-bold">Upload a photo of your object</h1>
  <div *ngIf="imagePaths.length" class="image-uploaded flex flex-col mt-16">
    <div class="flex space-x-2">
      <div *ngFor="let path of imagePaths" class="image-container relative">
        <img [src]="path" class="uploaded-image" alt="Uploaded image">
        <button class="delete-btn" (click)="deleteImage(path)">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="mt-4 text-center">Uploaded 100%</span>
  </div>
  <mat-spinner class="mt-16" *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
  <div class="image-upload cursor-pointer mt-16" (click)="imageInput.click()"
       *ngIf="!imagePaths.length && !isLoading">
    <mat-icon class="h-8 w-8">add</mat-icon>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*, .heic, capture=camera" (change)="onImageSelected($event)" #imageInput hidden>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the TS file:

```
 onImageSelected(event: Event) {
// @ts-ignore
const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];

if (file) {
  // Show a preview of the image
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = e => this.previewImage = reader.result;
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  // Start the upload
  this.startImagesUpload([file]);
}
```

}

```
startImagesUpload(files: File[]) {
this.isLoading = true;
this.imageUploadService.uploadImages(files).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.imagePaths = response.map((res: any) => res.path);
    this.formSteps.get('imageUploadCtrl')?.setValue(this.imagePaths[0]);
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();

    // handle response
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log('Image upload failed');
    console.log(error);
    this.isLoading = false;
    // handle error
  }
);
```

}

and this is my BE code:

```
router.post('/images', auth, cloudinary.uploadCloud.array('images', 4), async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    console.log(req.files);
    if (!req.files || !req.files.length) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'No image uploaded'});
    }

    // Assuming the middleware adds the Cloudinary URL as 'path' and the original filename as 'filename'
    const filesInfo = req.files.map(file => ({
        path: file.path, // URL to the uploaded image on Cloudinary
        filename: file.filename
    }));
    res.status(201).json(filesInfo);

} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    next(error);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was really with AWS beanstalk. so I'm not sure why is it happening but it was saying the file is too large, while uploading the same file from desktop was not too large?

anyway I solved the issue by adding `client_max_body_size 50M;` to my .conf